# error : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two tables and I need to add the value from specific cell in table_3 to table_4 .. but its not working. Any help please?

Code :

```
JTable table_3 = new JTable(TableModel2);
final JTable table_4 = new JTable(TableModel3);


JButton btnAdd = new JButton("add");
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int row = table_3.getSelectedRow();
    int column = table_3.getSelectedColumn();
    Object selectedPlanet = TableModel2.getValueAt(row, column);
    int columnContainingPlanets = 0;

    for (int index = columnContainingPlanets; index < TableModel3.getRowCount();index ++){
          Object value = TableModel3.getValueAt(index, columnContainingPlanets) ;
          if (value == selectedPlanet) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel_10,"This item was selected ,Please select another item");
          return; }}

    TableModel3.addRow(new Object[] { selectedPlanet });
            }
         });
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct, others are not. Be consistent! Variable names should also be descriptive. "3 and 4" is not very descriptive. And the model names are even worse ("2 and 3"). At the very least the model name should match the table names so we know which model belongs to which table. We can't tell why the table isn't updated. Did you add debug statement to verify the code is executed? If you need more help post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And make sure the code is properly formatted so it is readable.

Comment: yup, thats right but not affect in code running , anyway thanx for advice .

Comment: Still waiting for your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still waiting for your `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example(MCVE)`. What makes you think the problem is in the code you posted? Until a problem is solved every question should have a simple example demonstrating the problem which proves that you tried to simplify problem to better debug it.

What is the point of posting the error message without indicating the line of code causing the problem? Again another reason to post the `MCVE`. You don't know until the question is answered what information is needed to solve the problem.

Without all the information all we can do is guess.

As a newbie to the forum you get one guess. Future questions will require an `MCVE`

My guess is that the "tableModel3" doesn't have any columns, so you can't add a row to the model containing a single column of data.

So the model should be created with code something like:

```
String[] columnNames = { "Planets" };
DefaultTableModel tableModel3 = new DefaultTableMNodel(columnNames, 0);
```

Comment: your guess is right and am sorry i will work in your advice in next time . thanx for your effort ..